# How do i pass arguments to a javascript element from scala?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, raphael, morris.js

I need to feed a javascript element with values from a Map as shown below.

My render feeds the HTML document with:

```
@(morrisDonut: Map[String, Integer])
```

The JS looks like this:

```
$.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js',function(){
$.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js',function(){

var donutData = [];
@for((activity, steps) <- morrisDonut) {
    donutData.push({label: activity, value: steps});
}

Morris.Donut({
    element: 'user_activity-donut',
    data: donutData
});
});
});
```

The script stops because it dont can't find/can't use activity and steps even though its the correct types.

SOLUTION:

```
donutData.push({label: '@activity', value: @steps});
```

Adding " ' " and " @ " symbols seemed to work just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your syntax I *think* (and I'm inferring a lot here) that you're using the Play Framework - i.e. [Twirl templates](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ScalaTemplates). If that is the case, then you're just missing some deference operators (`@`) at the critical points where you are loading up your `donutData` array:

```
@for((activity, steps) <- morrisDonut) {
  donutData.push({label: @activity, value: @steps});
}
```

It can be tricky intermixing Twirl directives with another language because by design, there's no explicit "this is the end of my Twirl code" marker - it's all inferred. So in your case, the first and third lines were correctly interpreted by Twirl, but the second line appeared to just be some static content - which would be inserted as-is.

By adding the magic `@` symbols, the necessary substitution is detected.

Comment: Yes it is indeed play framework. the donutData.push arguments fails to insert the values even with the magic @ symbol. Any other tips i might try?

Comment: Have a look at the generated HTML/JS using your browser's View Source - it might show up something unusual happening